# How to clean up redundant bootstrap styles while still using bootstrap?

Tags: css, sass

Take multiple HTML elements with the same Bootstrap classes applied, for example

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4 bg-white color-blue">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 bg-white color-blue">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 bg-white color-blue">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

The problem is that you want to usually change the same style on multiple elements, and this doesn't sound like a good practice at all. The usual way to get rid of this redundancy would be something like

```
.container div 
{
  color:blue;
  ...
}
```

How do I mix the above solution so that it still uses Bootstrap's classes?

I'm up to solutions in CSS extensions too (Sass, Less, etc.).

Comment: Do you have the bootstrap sass in your build pipeline from their node module or something and have access to the `variables.scss` file? If so you can apply global changes like that right in there. Or (for simplicity) in the case of your example, simple style inheritance would suffice by instead doing like `class="container bg-white color-blue"` to avoid the W.E.T. approach also.

Comment: Looked a bit into it and Sass supports multiple inheritance, so this will be a suitable solution. (if you add it as an answer, I'll accept). Thanks.

Comment: Which one? The bootstrap suggestion was just an assumption that's what you're using. The second suggestion is just good ol fashioned style inheritance from parent to children.